# What is the use of quasi logarithmic frequency distribution in multisine frequency signal in finding FFT

Tags: fft, dft, frequency

I'm using multisine but recommended to use quasi log frequency distribution to find out FFT.

What is the advantage of using this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the mathematical definition of quasi log frequency distribution? Does it simply mean the frequency bins are distributed logarithmically?

Comment: You need to ask the person who recommended that. The FFT has inherently a linear frequency spacing and you definitely do NOT need a quasi log frequency distribution to "find an FFT". You way want to use a log frequency distribution for a spectral measurement that has a pink noise floor, but that's a totally different topic.